# python files not executing on server

Tags: python, server

I have installed python3.6 on root, created python_app folder inside public_html directory running this .py file

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "Hello world!!"
```

but it is rendered as plain text in browser,

> .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Any solution

Comment: "but it is rendered as plain text in browser" What does this mean? How are you running the code? Why does this show up in a browser at all? ...And why are you trying to output content headers directly on the standard output like this? CGI is really, really outdated.

Comment: python3.6 with python 2.x syntax ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : I have hosted ths file on sub domain accessing it through url, can you please give me link to run python app on centos

Comment: That doesn't even remotely answer my questions.

Comment: You need to use an `.htaccess` file to tell Apache that Python scripts are to be treated as CGI.  So, `Options +ExecCGI` and `Add-Handler cgi-script .py`.

Comment: @Kris : I have tried both the syntax on my server both python 2 and 3.6 are installed

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Apache to run your Python scripts as CGI.

Create or add this to `.htaccess`:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Make sure your Python file has a she-bang line at the very top so it can be run on its own:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

Make sure your file is executable:

```
chmod +x myfile.py
```

You can verify that it is set up properly by executing it from a command line:

```
./myfile.py
```

If that works, then Apache should be able to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have added my htaccess in my question, if i was adding these two lines then my htaccess was not working can you please update full htaccess

Comment: Just add it to the beginning or end, outside the `<IfModule..` section.  If you're going to be working with CGI, you need to understand `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I think there is some settings issue on my server because I tried to place python script in cgi-bin directory there also it is not working

Answer (score 0):

While the suggestion to use `ExecCGI` is good, I find it's better to use a WSGI implementation such as [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) instead.